# Use AVG & Count together

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2000, average

I am needing to take a average amount of sales.  But when I try to execute my query I get this error (again :( )
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Here is what I am attempting to run

```
Select SalesMan,
COUNT(CASE WHEN SalesMan IN ('Richard', 'Jose', 'Mendez') AND supCheck IS NOT NULL AND ordered IS      NOT NULL THEN AVG(price1+price2+price3+price4+price5) ELSE NULL END)
FROM PixieStick.dbo.SalesInfo
GROUP BY SalesMan
ORDER BY SalesMan ASC
```

Comment: Why have you put the average in a count this makes little sense what I think you want is simply `AVG(CASE WHEN ... THEN p1+p2+...+p5 END)`?

Comment: Leave it to me to over complicate a situation!  Thank you for your patience, btw

Comment: If you have solved the problem you should post the solution as an answer and mark it as excepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @T I

```
Select SalesMan,
AVG(CASE WHEN SalesMan IN ('Richard', 'Jose', 'Mendez') AND supCheck IS NOT NULL AND ordered IS        NOT NULL THEN price1+price2+price3+price4+price5 ELSE NULL END)
FROM PixieStick.dbo.SalesInfo
GROUP BY SalesMan
ORDER BY SalesMan ASC
```